# Add text to f:selectItems label in XHTML

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

Am trying to add to add text to `itemLabel`.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="firstRemindDaysBefore"  
                 value="#{vehicleController.vehicle.DaysBefore}"
                 valueChangeListener="#{vehicleController.reminderBeforeDays}">
       <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"/>
       <f:selectItems value="#{vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore}"
                      itemLabel="#{vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore} Days"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I have tried like this but not getting reflected.

```
itemLabel="#{vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore} Days"
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Please show code for vehicleController class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that:

```
vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore
```

is a List of some Day Objects, if I'm right than the code should look more or less like this:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="firstRemindDaysBefore"  
             value="#{vehicleController.vehicle.DaysBefore}"
             valueChangeListener="#{vehicleController.reminderBeforeDays}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="#{null}" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore}" var="day"
                  itemLabel="#{day.label} Days" itemValue="#{day}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

or if it is a List of Integers then:

```
<f:selectItems value="#{vehicleController.lstRemindDaysBefore}" var="day"
                  itemLabel="#{day} Days" itemValue="#{day}"/>
```